# How do remote sensors connect to a password-protected wifi network?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, wifi-configuration, sensors

I'm quite new to networking in general, and am wondering how remote sensing devices are able to connect to someone's home wifi network?

For example, take a device like this:
https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/edyn/edyn-welcome-to-the-connected-garden

How is such a device able to connect to a user's wifi if it's password-protected? What components (at a system level) need to work together to make this happen?

Thanks for your help!

Rohan

Comment: Did you read the FAQ of this device? https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/edyn/edyn-welcome-to-the-connected-garden#project_faq_92484?

Comment: @VMai thanks for that! So how does that work exactly? How can the app tell the chip which network to pair with, if the device is not yet connected to the WiFi?

Answer (score 1):

The devices are battery powered (topped up by the solar panel) and you configure them through the app via your smartphone.

The device probably uses a Bonjour or WiFi Direct system that the app on your phone then uses, through your phone wifi, to give you the ability to configure the remote device to connect to a router (I.e. from WiFi Direct (ad hoc) to infrastructure mode so it can then connect to the Internet and communicate with the cloud service the company offers.